# Using regex to get a value surrounded by " " Java

Tags: java, regex

I've used regex to get values surronded by ' ' but cannot find a way to use it for values with " ". Is there any other special characters I could use that are different than ' '.?

```
if (curVal.contains(searchArray))
            {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(curVal);
                if (matcher.find())
                {
                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                    names =matcher.group(1);

                }
            }
```

I cannot use ' ' again I need it to be unique or is there no other way to use regex?

Comment: What pattern do you try to use with double quotes and what result do you get?

Comment: use the same one but with `\"` instead, you do have to escape the `"`

Comment: Does `"\"(.*?)\""` not work?

Comment: @Sweeper I think you mean `"\"(.+)\""`

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotes in Java with a backslash so it won't end your string.
`System.out.println("This quote \" will not end my string.")`

prints:
`This quote " will not end my string.`